# Why am I signed out of XBox One with the message 'Bye! You've signed in to another XBox One'

Tags: xbox-one

I have had an intermittent problem with my XBox One. I get signed out unexpectedly with the message:

> 'Bye ...! You've signed in on another XBox One'

I've changed the password on my account but this has no effect. I originally created my account on a friend's XBox One, but haven't signed in on it for over sixth months. I asked them to remove my account from their XBox One and they say they have...

Comment: A Live profile can only be active on one Xbox One. It will automatically be signed out of any other console if you sign in to an Xbox One. Did you or someone else who has your account details sign into another Xbox One?

Comment: @Eric Good questions - I've updated my Question with more detail on this.

Comment: With the addition to your question, the steps outlined in your solution make sense. In essence, you want to remove the profile from your friend's console yourself remotely and not rely on them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sign in on this link first and change your account's password:
https://account.microsoft.com/security/

Once you've reset your account's password, go to this link:
https://account.microsoft.com/devices/

Then, check if you could see the Xbox One console on your signed in devices and remove it from your account.

Check the serial number of your XBox One (on the back of the device) and remove all other devices from the account.

Then, on your XBox One settings on the console, set the option 'Make this my home Xbox'.